# How to get Current Page/View or topmost Page/View in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to show `AlertDialog(DisplayAlert)` in a Xamarin.Forms project when an unhandled error occurs.

How can I get the current page instance?

Comment: I am using another way to accomplish showing an alertDialog from "everywhere". Do you need to do it with the current page/view? Or is it good enough just doing it?

Comment: Please cease the close and down votes its a perfectly valid xf question

Comment: Yes, i want showing an alertDialog from everywhere. @dsnunez

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep a reference of your main page as you mentioned. There are a few ways to do this.

1. You can have a static reference to it in your App.cs file, which is actually already there as it inherits from Application which has:

```
App.Current.MainPage
```

2. If you use an MVVM helper like MVVMLight you pass the page to the service so it keeps a reference of it.
3. ACR UserDialogs is a dialog package that can also help as it extends and adds different types of dialogs

Comment: I'm using something like your solution n°1 on my own app. When I first implemented it, I remember that on some excecution paths I was getting an exception (sorry, can't remember exactly which one was it, but it was something like a NullReference or an InvalidOperation) when I tried to display the AlertDialog. I solved it by wrapping my call to AlertDialog like this: 
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await MainPage.DisplayAlert("title", "message", "OK");
                });

Answer (score 1):

To get around this and have a lot more flexibility add 'ACR User Dialogs' package to each of your platform's projects.

Then you can use that from anywhere :

```
await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync ("Your question has been successfully sent", "Thankyou");
```